# How to use Hibernate Envers (@Audited) without Hibernate generating any tables

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, hibernate-envers

We have a situation where we don't allow Hibernate to create( re-create) tables. We use Hibernate 4.x with Spring.

We wanted to create the tables manually by running our own Oracle sql script with "AUD" extension.

For simplicity purpose, I have the following class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ENVERS_TEST")
public class EnversTest {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ENV_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "ENVERS_TEST_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "ENVERS_TEST_SEQ", sequenceName = "ENVERS_TEST_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)

    private Integer envId;

    @Audited
    @Column(name = "CREATED_BY")
    private String createdBy;

    @Audited
    @Column(name = "UPDATED_DATE")
    private Date updatedDate;


    @NotAudited
    @Column(name = "DESCR")
    private String description;

    //getters and setters

}
```

At the beginning, I setup another DB schema and used

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

And found out the following sql was generated automatically.

```
  CREATE TABLE "BDR"."ENVERS_TEST_AUD" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"REV" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"REVTYPE" NUMBER(3,0), 
"CREATED_BY" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR), 
"UPDATED_DATE" TIMESTAMP (6), 
PRIMARY KEY ("ID", "REV")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 
  TABLESPACE "DBA_DATA1_TS"  ENABLE, 
CONSTRAINT "FK_4637U2YFKSOKDFIXCWWL37ANH" FOREIGN KEY ("REV")
 REFERENCES "BDR"."REVINFO" ("REV") ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  TABLESPACE "DBA_DATA1_TS" ;
```

So I copied this SQL and tried to run on another schema but the line

REFERENCES "BDR"."REVINFO" ("REV") ENABLE

is causing a problem because

`REVINFO`

doesn't exist. Most examples I saw only talk about the AUD table but not the `REVINFO`. Does it mean there is also another table called `REVINFO` that holds time stamp and revision id? I couldn't find the structure of this table.

Please let me know how we can create this table manually. What is it's structure ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally was able to create another schema to test and find the REVINFO table sql statement. You should run this sql before running the sql to create base class and AUD table. Here it is!!

```
  CREATE TABLE "REVINFO" 
   (    "REV" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"REVTSTMP" NUMBER(19,0), 
PRIMARY KEY ("REV")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 
  TABLESPACE "DBA_DATA1_TS"  ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  TABLESPACE "DBA_DATA1_TS" ;
```

**The problem was most of the documentations and tutorials I went through only talk about the _AUD table not the REVINFO table.**